# Whitelist Parameters in Controller without a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to whitelist a parameter from my `params`. I have a controller `ElectiveRecommendationsController` that isn't tied to any Model.

[image]

How do I whitelist my `:electives`? I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
def permitted_params
  params.permit(:electives)
end
```

The error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't your `puts params[:electives].to_h` be `puts permitted_params[:electives].to_h` as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that `electives` is a `Hash`. You'll want this

```
def permitted_params
  params.permit(electives: {})
end
```